# Emit event not firing in .on() callback on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to build a system where one node controlls the other like this:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8000);

io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("origins = *");
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});




var screen = io.of('/screen').on('connection', function (socket) {
    screen.emit('news', { hello: 'screen' });
  });

var controls =  io.of('/controls').on('connection', function (socket) {
    controls.emit('news', { hello: 'world 2' });

    controls.on('controlPressed', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        screen.emit('cp', data);
    });

  });
```

however in the callback of controlPressed does log the data but doesn't emit the event screen.emit('cp', data);

When I emit the event outside the callback the client receives it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong with my logic. I tried using express and this way it works now:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , Moniker = require('moniker')
  , express = require("express")
  , app = express()
  , port = process.env.PORT || 8000
  ;


app.set('port', port);
app.get('/controlls', function(req, res){


 fs.readFile(__dirname + '/controlls.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });

});

app.get('/', function(req, res){

 fs.readFile(__dirname + '/screen.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });


});

server = app.listen(8000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var interfaces = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('hello', function(data){

        interfaces[data.screen] = client;
        console.log(interfaces);
    });

    if(interfaces['controlls'] && interfaces['screen']){

    interfaces['controlls'].on('controlPressed', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        interfaces['screen'].emit('cp', data);
    });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better do it like this:

```
io.of('namespace').emit('cp', data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Unfortunatly that also didnt work. Also i've tried emmiting it to the controlls. That also didn't work.

Comment: your code seems okay but have you referenced your client code to these namespaces? Also,try using the default configuration by removing io.configure() method and see if it works. If yes, then problem is in your own defined configuration because you're not allowing socket.io to use preferable transports

Comment: I think there was something wrong in my logic. I tried it in a different way now and it works.